# Is There any MySQL manual in *.chm format??

Tags: mysql, manual

According to Mysql documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/ there is no official mysql manual in CHM format, but there are other formats including HTML Single page and HTML Page/chapter that can be compiled into CHM.

I want to know if there are any that has been compiled into CHM that are ready to use out there?

Comment: I googled and didn't find anything the latest version of myman is 5.0.3 i'm using 5.5.9 and i know the same website has a utility called html2hhp that was written 6 years ago and from that time structure of MySql html manual has changed significantly.

Comment: I needed mysql 5.6 chm manual and I made it. https://www.mediafire.com/file/s00zboo2xr1l61a/mysql-refman-5.6-en.chm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an official .chm version of the documentation maintained by MySQL team. However they decided to stop it.

http://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlf/entry/farewell_chm_hello_epub

What remains are more or less outdated thirdparty .chm versions of the official .html manual.

Answer (score 4):

Try http://code.google.com/p/popsrc/downloads/detail?name=mysql-refman-5.5-en.chm

Comment: it's obsolete now!

Answer (score 2):

I can't vouch for this, but a quick search of Google yielded the following manual: http://phlab.net/myman/

It appears to be a third party version of the MySQL manual in .chm format.

Comment: This is the outdated manual I'm using 5.5.9